# Visual C++ и C++11: non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio, c++11, c++, visual-studio-2012

Доброго времени суток уважаемые. У меня следующий вопрос: 
При попытке скомпилировать вот этот код

```
map<string, int> m = { { "a", 1 }, { "b", 2 } };
```

он выругался вот такими словами:

> non-aggregates cannot be initialized with initializer list

или по-русски:

> объекты, не являющиеся агрегатами, не могут быть инициализированы с помощью списка инициализации

Насколько я знаю последний стандарт языка позволяет подобные конструкции. 
Стоит Visual Studio 2012 Update 2, версия компилятора 17.0.60315.1
Собственно вопрос: насколько хорошо компилятор от Microsoft поддерживает последний стандарт С++11 и могу ли я вообще обновить компилятор если есть  более новая версия? (достаточно ли для этого просто заменить cl.exe?) 
P.S. сам факт полной поддержки стандарта принципиального значения не имеет, просто интересно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что и как поддерживает  vc++, можно увидеть [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx). Затрудняюсь сказать, насколько эта информация актуальна, и обновляется ли она с выходом новых версий компилятора, но, думаю, она близка к правде. (Для сравнения примерно то же для gcc - [вот](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) Как можно видеть, тут картина куда как радужнее)

По поводу обновления компилятора - возможно [это](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515) будет полезно. (Впрочем, 17.0.60315.1 - это, по-моему, и так его последняя версия)

Answer (score 4):

Ваша конструкция правильна: http://ideone.com/iBm6Ti

Судя по всему, VS 2012 не полностью поддерживает текущий стандарт.

Простой заменой компилятора вы ничего не добьётесь, нужно ещё и менять заголовочные файлы, рантайм-библиотеки (они могут быть специфичные для компилятора), компоновщик, и т. п. Короче, заменить весь набор средств.

---

[Вот](https://web.archive.org/web/20160127043203/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) обзор того, что поддерживается, от команды разработчиков.

Comment: нет, я это знаю, просто меня интересует насколько "не полностью" и можно ли как-то обновить компилятор

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем по теме, но в таком случае может выручить `boost.assign`

Answer (score 0):

[VC++11 November 2012 CTP](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx?Redirected=true) вроде как поддерживает универсальную инициализацию и `initializer_list` (сам не пробовал), но стандартная библиотека ещё пока не обновлена до них, так что стандартные контейнеры типа `std::map` всё равно не будут с ней работать